# Why is RemoveRange failing on entities already being tracked?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

After adding an entry using entities collection of DB context, if I try to call RemoveRange I get an InvalidOperationException.

If I use another instance of the DB context to call RemoveRange, then it works fine. But when I use the same DB context, it fails.

```
var ingredient = new Ingredient()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Pepper",
};
await context.Ingredients.AddAsync(ingredient);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();

context.Ingredients.RemoveRange(context.Ingredients);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The error message is :

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Ingredient' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{IngredientId: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

If I understood correctly, Remove() and RemoveRange() would attach the entity if it were not already tracked. In my case, an instance is already being tracked... true... but then,

**what would be the correct way to remove all entries, without caring which entities are already tracked and which are not yet tracked ?**

Any clue ?

Comment: What other data is in the corresponding table with `Ingredient`? I don't think you want to explicitly set an `Id` column in general, and it seems like that's what is causing your problem.

Comment: The problem occurs even when Ingredients id the only table. The Id column is just an int as a primary key.

Comment: Try removing `Id = 0,` and see how it handles inserting the new entity. If it's a primary key then you don't want to specify its value. Your DB engine (with some exceptions) should handle identity columns in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the line `context.Ingredients.RemoveRange(context.Ingredients);` by the following:

```
var tempIngredients = context.Ingredients.ToList(); 
context.Ingredients.RemoveRange(tempIngredients);
```

Comment: I tried. Same error : [...] another instance with the key value is already being tracked [...]